# What should I return in an error case in a function expected to return a Template<T> value?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm quite noob yet in OOP and is my first time handling exceptions and Templates, may be I planned the function in a wrong way...
But I would like to know what should I return in this case if the execution goes wrong and the exception is thrown.... what kind of data error return in a function returning a Template?
Sorry if I am not clear enough, english is not my mothertongue...

```
template<typename T>
const T& List<T>::Next()
{
    try
    {
        if (_actual->getNext() == NULL)
            throw out_of_range("No next elements, list out of bounds");
        else
        {
            _actual = _actual->getNext();
            _Position++;
            return _actual->getData();
        }
    }
    catch (out_of_range &e)
    {
        cerr << "Error, " << e.what() << endl << "Position: " << _Position << " Elements: " << _Elements << endl;
    }
// <--- what should I return here?? return NULL;? return 0;? return <T> thrash;??
}
```

Comment: What about rethrowing the exception?

Comment: _"I am quite noob yet in POO"_ What on earth does this mean?!

Comment: May be.... is that the usual way to maneuver in these kind of situations?

Comment: hahahaha sorry guys I mixed my language with english... i meant OOP!!! Loooool!!!

Comment: Why should a _list_ know what the _client's_ current element is?

Comment: yes, maybe it's not the usual way but I wanted to make for my own use a List with full functionality on it and don't depend on nodes methods... but that's not the more important point in the question... :)

Comment: @black It's not unheard of to embed a single cursor within a list. Look at PHP's arrays, for example, or MySQL recordsets. It makes for simpler usage semantics in certain domains. Not everything has to be super generic, reentrant and reusable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's nothing to return then there's nothing to return.

Let the exception propagate, either by *not catching it here*, or by re-throwing it after your `cerr` statement with the `throw` statement:

```
catch (out_of_range &e)
{
    cerr << "Error, " << e.what() << endl
         << "Position: " << _Position
         << " Elements: " << _Elements << endl;
    throw;
}
```

Your next question will be how to handle the exception in the calling scope. :)
But at least you won't have to worry about return values any more.

Comment: reading your answer and first user, I assume that is the usual way to handle this situation.... thanks for your advice!!! that will work for me :) any other suggestion will also be welcome!! :)

Comment: Careful about `_Position` and `_Elements`.

Comment: @black: "Careful" how?

Comment: Well, they're reserved names. Technically it's UB. So I'd say careful enough.

Comment: @black: Right, true. See, it's better when you actually say what you mean instead of just saying "careful"!

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I'll be more careful with that too.